# Regex Or Not Match

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following numbers representing phone numbers:

- +16085551212
- +16089111212

I currently have got `.[0-9][2-9][0-9]{2}[2-9][0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}` which works for both numbers.

However I cannot figure out the criteria for having the 6th and 7th number not being allowed to be 11 to avoid possible 911 references as shown in the above. From reading around I expect it is some form of lookahead possibly but I am not entirely sure, nor have a clue how to implement into the already existing pattern.

Comment: Any explanation as to how the given answer functions would also be appreciated :)

Comment: What language/system are you using? That's pretty important here, because indeed, lookahead assertions would be the canonical solution (nice research!)---however not all implementations support them.

Comment: Sorry for not including, its a C# execution

Comment: I think you should be able to solve this using negative lookahead. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: When people ask clarifying questions (like "what technology?"), it's usually a hint to you that you should edit your question and add more tags. Also, *because* you can edit your questions, there should never be a need for you to comment in immediate reply to your own questions - if you have more to add, just edit.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Fair points; I still appreciate a comment though---otherwise I'm not notified to return to the thread.

Comment: @Damien, apologies, will note for future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# supports lookarounds, extensively, so you're good to go. Here's how to use them in the specific way you've described:

```
.[0-9][2-9][0-9]{2}[2-9](?!11)[0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}
                        ^^^^^^
```

That's called a **negative lookahead assertion**.

However, this will make your regex much more transparent, especially for others:

```
.(?!\d*911)[0-9][2-9][0-9]{2}[2-9][0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}
 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Will accept shortly, will do the background reading also linked in the original post to further understanding, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're looking for a way to exclude any `911` inside the number.

You could do it with a regex like this: `(?!.+911.+)\+1[2-9][0-9]{2}[2-9][0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}`

Comment: The criteria only wants it in the position specified in the original question, it is a training question with 3 requirements, trying to get them all in one regex expression

Comment: Thanks Mike, see acheong87's answer in that case.